# How to Get Correct Row with Max Keyword in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, max

I have the following table with data.

```
create table tutorials_tbl(
   id INT NOT NULL,
   title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   votes int(10) NOT NULL,
   email VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
);

insert into tutorials_tbl values(1,'a',400,'400@email.com');
insert into tutorials_tbl values(2,'a',600,'600@email.com');
insert into tutorials_tbl values(3,'a',500,'500@email.com');
```

When I run `select *,max(votes) from tutorials_tbl`, it return following row.

```
id  title   votes   email   max(votes)
1   a   400 400@email.com   600
```

What expected and I want is,

```
id  title   votes   email   max(votes)
2   a   600 600@email.com   600
```

What is the problem with my query and how can I get the desired result using MAX keyword?

You can test this on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b60fba/3

Comment: Shouldn't the output have `id as 2`.

Comment: @Utsav my mistake, update the question. it should be 2 as id.

Comment: Do you want the output to be grouped by title or in any case the should have only one row with max votes?

Comment: `max()` is not the best way to write this logic.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Would you please mind sharing the best way?

Answer (score 1):

This is one way, with a subquery:

```
WITH M as (select max(votes) as votes from tutorials_tbl)
    select *, votes as max from tutorials_tbl NATURAL JOIN M;
```

alternatively you can do:

```
select *, votes as max from tutorials_tbl 
where votes = (select max(votes) tutorials_tbl);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *, max(votes) from tutorials_tbl where votes = (select max(votes) from tutorials_tbl )
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b60fba/6

**Output**

| id | title | votes | email | max(votes) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | a | 600 | 600@email.com | 600 |

Answer (score 0):

select T.*,T1.votes maxVotes
from tutorials_tbl T
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(votes)votes FROM tutorials_tbl)T1 ON T.Votes = T1.VOTES

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row with maximum votes (even if there are duplicates), then use:

```
select t.*
from tutorials_tbl t
order by votes desc
limit 1;
```

If you want all rows in the event of ties, then use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from tutorials_tbl t
where t.votes = (select max(t2.votes) from tutorials_tbl t);
```

(Okay, that does use `max()`.)

Or window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, rank() over (order by votes desc) as seqnum
      from tutorials_tbl t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```